# Const correctness in generic functions using iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, const-correctness

I want to write a generic functions that takes in a sequence, while guaranteeing to not alter said sequence.

```
template<typename ConstInputIter, typename OutputIter>
OutputIter f(ConstInputIter begin, ConstInputIter end, OutputIter out)
{
  InputIter iter = begin;
  do
  {
    *out++ = some_operation(*iter);
  }while(iter!=end);
  return out;
}
```

Yet the above example still would take any type as `ConstInputIterator`, not just `const` ones. So far, the notion towards being `const` in it is nominal.

How do I declare the sequence given will not be altered by this function?

Comment: Minor point: the usual convention is that the member functions that return iterators are named `begin()` and `end()`, while the iterators that are used to walk through a sequence are named `first` and `last`.

Comment: In c++20, it'd be somewhat easier; in c++17, write some docs in comments of the function. (Yes, there are ways to try to ensure this, but in general it's not worth it.)

Comment: Assuming the iterators will be "normal" std ones, you can change your template types to to be the container types, and then `begin/first` will be e.g. `typename T::const_iterator` etc.

Comment: I'd suggest it doesn't matter if the function can accept a non-const iterator, since it won't change the container anyway.   I suppose there is a possibility that copy-initialising an iterator (`InputIter iter = begin`) or comparing them (`iter!=end`) changes the container, but I've yet to encounter such an iterator in the real world.

Comment: @Peter Will make for a generic, incomprehensible scream from the compiler if someone does insert a non-const iterator, but that seems generally acceptable, indeed.

Comment: @Meph  Generic incomprehensible screams from a compiler are part of the spice of C++ development ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in C++20, there is no generic way to coerce an iterator over a non-`const` `T` into an iterator over a `T const`. Particular iterators may have a mechanism to do that, and you can use `std::cbegin/cend` for ranges to get const iterators. But given *only* an iterator, you are at the mercy of what the user provides.

Applying a C++20 constraint (requiring `iter_value_t` to be `const`) is the wrong thing, as your function should be able to operate on a non-`const` range.

Comment: C++23 exposition-only concepts [`constant-iterator`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2278r3.html#pnum_2) might help.

Comment: Both probably valid answers, thanks for sharing. Yet I tagged C++17, as those standards a yet unreachable for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Since [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), you can use [`std::as_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) every time you deference your iterator:

```
// ...
*out++ = some_operation(std::as_const(*iter));
// ...
```

This makes sure you never access the elements of the underlying container through a non-`const` l-value reference.

**Note:** if you don't have access to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), it's pretty trivial to implement your own version of `std::as_const`. Just make sure you declare it outside of namespace `std`.

Comment: To my understanding this would at least be a good practice when implementing such a function. As @Peter pointed out under the question: If the function does not change anything it does not have to be const. Your way you can at least at one point explicitly state intended constness early, so it does not become a problem further down in the function.